# Ajax GET request failing

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have an ajax request as follows:

```
permissionRequestModel.showApprovers = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ec6484646848compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/Request/permission?appid=1&opertype=requestor,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(){
        alert("failed");
    },
    success: function (data) {
          alert("Success");
    }
    });
};
```

which is failing, but the requested URL is returning the JSON response in the Rest Client on chrome properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having cross domain issues?

Comment: I guess I might be having cross-domain issues, my apis are hosted an amazon ec2 instance, know of any workaround for this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards the issue, that was indeed the problem. Solved it by 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the server-side.